# LINQ XML - Retrieve unknown name and value from XElement

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xsd

I am currently struggle to parse the following XML/XSD.

I have a list of 'Fields' in my XSD that must be one of the following:

```
<xs:element name="Field">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>Element to describe a selection by specified field values (decoded values).</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:attribute name="subsystem_ident" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:attribute name="failure_type" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:attribute name="failure_type_code" type="xs:unsignedShort" />
        <!-- list continues -->
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

I have another Element that contains these fields:

```
<xs:element name="Include">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">                   
                <xs:element ref="Field" />
                <xs:element ref="Time"/>
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

So in the XML this looks something like:

```
 <Include>
   <Field failure_type="Blah" />
   <Field failure_type_id="2" />
 </Include>
```

Now, because I don't really know the element name for each of the Fields I'm getting, I'm struggling to parse them. I'm also struggling to find exactly what I need to search for in order to do this. My field class simply has three properties:

```
public string Name { get; set; } // Should ultimately be an enum.
public Type Type { get; set; }
public string Value { get; set; }
```

Can someone help fill in the blanks for my XML Parsing method?

```
//
    Include = RetrieveFields(matchExpElement.Elements("Match").Elements("Include").Elements("Field")),
//

private List<Field> RetrieveFields(IEnumerable<XElement> fieldElements)
{          
    var fields = from x in fieldElements
                 select new Field()
                 {
                     Name = 
                     Type = 
                     Value = 
                 };

     return fields.ToList();
}
```

Comment: How is the XML supposed to map into your class?  For your example XML, what are you expecting to be in `Name`, `Type` and `Value`?

Comment: @Mark - The Name should be the field name, eg "failure_type". The Value should be the value, eg "Blah", and the Type should be the type specified in the xsd - in this case it's a string. The former are easier than the latter, and I can parse them outside of LINQ, but I would prefer a more consistent solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the schema type information for the attributes, you will first need to [validate your XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb354954%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) against the schema and have it build the post-schema-validation infoset (the last parameter to the `Validate` method).

```
var schemas = new XmlSchemaSet();
schemas.Add("", @"C:\Path\To\Your\schema.xsd");
var xml = @"
    <Match>
        <Include>
            <Field failure_type='Blah' />
            <Field failure_type_code='2' />
        </Include>
    </Match>
";
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
doc.Validate(schemas, (s, e) => { Console.WriteLine(e); }, true);
```

You can then reference this information in your LINQ to XML query to build your `Field` objects - note the call the `GetSchemaInfo`.

```
var fields =
    from f in doc.Elements("Match").Elements("Include").Elements("Field")
    let attr = f.Attributes().First()
    select new Field() {
        Name = attr.Name.LocalName,
        Type = attr.GetSchemaInfo()
                .SchemaAttribute.AttributeSchemaType.Datatype.ValueType,
        Value = attr.Value
    };
```

I got the following result in LINQPad:

[image: LINQPad Results]

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know you could use the schema to get into it like that, that's hugely helpful!